# Excel - How to freeze columns 1 to 4 and rows 1 to 4 simultaneously

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have tried to freeze columns 1 to 4 and rows 1 to 4 at the same time but it didn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Select cell `E5`.

Then, under the `View` tab, open the `Freeze Panes` menu and click `Freeze Panes`.

[image]